# Страница Login в Spring Security не вызывается для входящего USER

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Дорогие форумчане Java 
Не могу понять логику регистрации в Spring Security
Я делаю так:

```
1. Создаю класс реализующий WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity (prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")  // #1
          .password("password")
          .roles("USER")
          .and()
        .withUser("admin") // #2
          .password("password")
          .roles("ADMIN","USER");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
         .antMatchers("/resources/**"); // #3
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.html")
        .failureUrl("/login-error.html")
      .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html");
    }
  }



2. Регистрирую данный класс 

public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] {DaraServisConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class};
      //return null;
   }
   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

      return new Class[] {ASdf.class};
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}



3. Представление вывожу так

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.vokmar" }) 
@EnableWebMvc
public class ASdf implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    //1. Creating SpringResourceTemplateResolver
    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver springTemplateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver springTemplateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        springTemplateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        springTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        springTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        springTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        springTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return springTemplateResolver;
    }
    //2. Creating SpringTemplateEngine
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        springTemplateEngine.setTemplateResolver(springTemplateResolver());
        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    //3. Registering ThymeleafViewResolver
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(springTemplateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }  

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        //registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}


4. Главная страница 

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Welcome</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Приветствую!</h1>
      <div th:replace="~{fragment/meny :: meny}"></div>  // тут ссылка на закрытый раздел
   </body>
</html>

    5. Закрытый раздел /ок

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ОК</h1>
        <div th:replace="~{fragment/meny :: meny}">
         ДАварпвыиdfbdfbd 
      </div> 
        <div th:each="v : ${vendor}">

         <a th:href="@{'/edit?id='+${v.id}}">   <div th:text=${v.name}></div></a>
        </div>



    </body>
</html>


6. Контроллер 

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    private VendorServise sv;

       @RequestMapping("/login.html")
    public String log() {
        return "login";
    }

      @RequestMapping("/login-error.html")
  public String loginError(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
    return "login.html";
  }
```

Что я делаю не так, почему при нажатии на ссылку ведущую на закрытый раздел сайта страница login не выводится.

Comment: Мои зависимости:    spring-security-config,  spring-batch-core, spring-security-web

Comment: Контроллер для /ok :       @RequestMapping(value = "/ok", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ok(Model mu) {
        List<Vendor> df = sv.findByName();
        mu.addAttribute("vendor", df); 
        return "ok";